# How to turn off a frozen iPhone with a broken lock button?

Tags: iphone, ios

What can you do when your iPhone is in Airplane Mode, the WiFi is off, and the lock button is broken. I can't log in to the phone. How can I turn it off?

Answer (score 0):

You can let the battery run down, at which point the phone will power itself down. You can run its battery down slightly faster by waking it up using the home button -- this will activate the display backlight and run the battery down a bit faster.